# deleting only child pages using curl in CQ5

Tags: curl, aem

I am trying to delete only child pages using curl in CQ5 with this command

```
curl -X DELETE http://%HOSTAUTHOR%:%PORTAUTHOR%/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/ \
     -u %USER%:%PASSWORD%
```

I want only the pages under `/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/` to be deleted and not the 'g' page.  But the parent page also gets deleted.

Trying:

```
curl -X DELETE %HOSTAUTHOR%:%PORTAUTHOR%/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/* \
     -u %USER%:%PASSWORD%
```

does not delete anything, and trying…

```
curl -X DELETE %HOSTAUTHOR%:%PORTAUTHOR%/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g \
     -u %USER%:%PASSWORD%
```

deletes the 'g' page as well.

Can anybody help me in writing the correct syntax so that only the pages under `/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/` get deleted and not the whole 'g' page as well?

Answer (score 1):

As per [the Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html), you can do this with the `:applyTo` parameter:

> If the last segment of the `:applyTo` value is '*' then the operation
>   applies to all the children of the resolved parent resource. This can
>   be used to act on all the children of a resource without having to
>   specify the path of each individual child resource.
>
> …
>
> When specifying the item(s) to be removed with the `:applyTo` parameter, **the request resource is left untouched** (unless of course if listed in the `:applyTo` parameter) and only used to resolve any relative paths in the `:applyTo` parameter.

The syntax would be:

```
curl -u [user]:[password] \ 
     -F":operation=delete" \
     -F":applyTo=/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/*" \    
      http://[host]:[port]
```

Note that it also mentions if one resource fails to delete, the whole operation will fail.

Comment: I tried this; it deletes the jcr:content node of the parent page as well. Can we write it in a way that the jcr:content node of the parent page does not get deleted?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, it doesn't seem to support regex or globbing, unfortunately. Using multiple `applyTo` fields, e.g. one for each direct descendant, would be one way to do it (if cURL is a must), e.g. `curl -F":operation=delete" -F":applyTo=/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/primary" -F":applyTo=/content/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/secondary" http://localhost:8080 -u admin:admin`

Comment: Yes curl is a must in this use-case; and using multiple applyTo is not an option; since there are hundreds of pages. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ah, I see. If it's acceptable to run multiple commands you could pass the outcome of a GET through something like [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and then xargs back into cURL, but don't think you can do if as one straight command